# Why run sudo apt-get update before installing a package?

Tags: updates, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “sudo apt-get update” do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Why do we have to run `sudo apt-get update` before I can run `sudo apt-get install package`?

I found this very annoying when I am installing a lot of packages.  Or can I skip the `sudo apt-get update` part?