# What does "sudo apt-get update" do?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

I am wondering what `sudo apt-get update` does?

What does it update?

Answer (score 708, accepted):

In a nutshell, `apt-get update` doesn't actually install new versions of software. Instead, it updates the package lists for upgrades for packages that need upgrading, as well as new packages that have just come to the repositories.

- `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories and PPAs.
  From http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get:

  > Used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list`(5). An update should always be performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade.
- `apt-get upgrade` will fetch new versions of packages existing on the machine if APT knows about these new versions by way of `apt-get update`.

  From http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get:

  > Used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in `/etc/apt/sources.list`(5). Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, nor are packages that are not already installed retrieved and installed. **New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another package will be left at their current version.** [Emphasis mine] An update must be performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` ([on `apt` equivalent to `full-upgrade`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html)) will do the same job which is done by `apt-get upgrade`, plus it will also intelligently handle the dependencies, so it might remove obsolete packages or add new ones. See here: [What is "dist-upgrade" and why does it upgrade more than "upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

  From http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get:

  > In addition to performing the function of upgrade, this option also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones, if necessary.
  > The `/etc/apt/sources.list`(5) file contains a list of locations from
  > which to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for over-riding the general settings for individual packages.

You can combine commands with `&&` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install foo bar baz foo-dev foo-dbg
```

or to get newest versions possible as per version requirements of dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You need `sudo` both times, but since `sudo` by default doesn't prompt you within 5 or so minutes since the last `sudo` operation, you will be prompted for your password only once (or not at all).

Comment: Do we always need to run `sudo apt-get update` command whenever we install packages? What's the disadvantage if we don't do so?

Comment: @JohnnyQ If you do not run that command then you may get an out-of-date package installed.

Comment: ah sounds like it's just a convention thing then. So I'm assuming it's really no that necessary especially if you are just using basic packages with basic commands that don't get updated usually. Problem in my situation is that `apt-get update` takes a while, internet here is still primitive.

Comment: @JohnnyQ For some packages it's quite important that your package lists be up to date. Examples of such packages include security-critical software.

Comment: @JohnnyQ, if your apt-get update is slow, then your apt-get dist-upgrade will also be slow, so that's not really an argument not to do apt-get update first. Btw, you can speed up your apt-get update by looking into the folder /etc/apt/sources.d/ to see if you have any custom repositories added and one of those might be unresponsive, which will slow down entire update process.

Comment: By the way, "apt" stands for Advanced Packaging Tool ( https://wiki.debian.org/Apt  "What is APT?").  Something I learned the other day, thought I'd share. ("apt" appears often in man apt-get, man apt, but I had never seen the acronym expanded before).

Comment: Why not have upgrade do the same as dist-upgrade? Many people only use upgrade while things fall behind.

Comment: @izk9 I'm not sure why they didn't just have one command with a flag to hold upgrades more restrictively. It's probably a question to the apt designers.

Answer (score 59):

A Google search can give you the definition for almost any terminal command, as can --help in the terminal. For example,

```
apt-get --help
```

`sudo apt-get update` essentially has three parts:

```
sudo
```

performs the following command with super-user (root) capabilities. Many actions that require modifying system files or installing applications require extra permissions to go through.

```
apt-get
```

is a command-line tool which Ubuntu uses to install, remove, and manage software packages

```
update
```

is an option for the apt-get program to use which updates the package lists from a server on the internet. The package lists provide the apt-get utility with important information about the software packages that you can install using apt-get. apt-get uses these lists to determine which software to install when given a command to install. For example

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

would install the Guake terminal as it is currently listed in my computer's local software lists. This may not, however, be the appropriate version, or if the program is new, it might not be available at all. Thus, when installing software with apt-get, you typically type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

ensuring that apt-get knows to install the most recent version of the package.

Another useful source for information is the `help.ubuntu.com` site. For example, if you searched that site for `apt-get` you would find [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) as one of the results.

Comment: Alex, can I basically use the command like you put it: 
"apt-get update
apt-get install <package>"

Basically 2 things can be performed just typing the 2 commands together like this?

Comment: @Elysium Yes, if you have `&&` between them as `sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get install foo bar baz`

Comment: Using `&&` means that the second command will only run if the first one succeeds. If you don't care about the success of the first command, use `;` instead.

Comment: A Google search led me to this question/answer. Just FYI ;)

Comment: Anyone know why this isn't just done on every boot up automatically, or in the cron? Seems like an extra admin step.

Comment: @DanChase [reddit: Is "sudo apt-get update" on startup a good idea or bad? Why?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1ycreq/is_sudo_aptget_update_on_startup_a_good_idea_or/) has a decent discussion why `apt-get update` is not run on boot-up. Basically: don't update anything on my system w/o my consent. However, you could add a script in the cron if you want that behavior.

Answer (score 25):

Running `sudo apt-get update` simply makes sure your list of packages from all repositories and PPA's is up to date. If you do not run this command, you could be getting older versions of various packages you are installing, or worse, dependency issues. If you have just added a PPA and have not updated, nothing from the PPA will work at all as you do not have a package list from that PPA or repository.

In a nutshell: It is *highly* recommended to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing, but it *may be skipped if you are really pressed for time* unless you have changed repositories or PPAs since the last `apt-get update`.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm installing multiple 2 packages for example do I put apt-get update twice or just once? Is it update for ALL packages or the ones that follow it? (if that makes sense)

Comment: @RobertSinclair Once is enough - it pulls package lists from all repositories. Running `sudo apt update` the second time doesn't do anything new unless you either add a *repository*, or the repository *maintainers* add/update packages in the repository.

Answer (score 19):

It updates the available software list on your computer.

Your computer has a list (like a catalog) that contains all the available software that the Ubuntu servers have available. But the available software and versions might change, so a "update" will hit the server and see what software is available in order to update its local lists (or catalogs).

Note that `update` is diferent from `upgrade`. Update, as mentioned above, will fetch available software and update the lists while `upgrade` will install new versions of software installed on your computer (actual software updates).

To actually upgrade your software (not "update" the lists), you execute the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which is usually executed after an "update".

Answer (score 13):

You need to run `apt-get update` once before installing new packages as this updates the local repository information.

If you are going to install multiple packages shortly after each other, you do not need to run `apt-get update` before each install; just once before the first install.

Also, you can install multiple packages at once if you type
`sudo apt-get install package1 package2...`, but you still need to run `apt-get update` prior to the multiple package install.

Comment: Nice trick for that!

Answer (score 8):

When you install packages from the command line with `sudo apt-get install ...` (or `sudo aptitude install ...`), or when you upgrade them from the command line (with `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` instead of `install`), the following information is obtained from your local system's configuration, and *not* from the Internet:

1. what packages are available
2. **what versions of them are available**
3. where the available packages should be retrieved from

Running `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo aptitude update`) updates this on your local system. This is the step that actually retrieves information about what packages can be installed, **including what updates to currently installed packages packages are available**, from Internet sources.

When you install packages with a GUI interface (the Update Manager, the Software Center, or the Synaptic Package Manager), the work of `sudo apt-get update` is done automatically. When you install packages from the command-line, it is not, and you should always do this yourself *unless you have done so very recently*.

Because information about what updated versions of packages are available is obtained by running `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo aptitude update`), it is advisable to run this before installing any package, and necessary to run it to install the latest updates, *even if you have not added or removed any Software Sources (such as a PPA)*.

Please note that if you are going to perform multiple package management operations around the same time, you don't need to run `sudo apt-get update` before each one. It's only if the information hasn't been updated for a while, that you should make sure to run it.

Answer (score 4):

As said by plenty of people before me this updates your local repository (package list).

You may run into trouble if you try to install

```
apt-get install foobar
```

and foobar or a dependency don't have their latest version in the repository. This can be especially problematic if installing a .deb file manually or a ppa from a 3rd party.

Basically it makes sure *your list* matches the *master* list.

Answer (score 4):

As Eliah Kagan mentioned above, you would **expect** that a GUI application would run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install` / `apt-get upgrade`, but I just discovered an interesting error 404, on a relatively new offensive-security VM machine, that had me stumped for a minute.

From the command line, I ran `apt-get update`, and then tried the System Tools/Software-Update command again, and this time it ran with no 404 errors.

So, I guess you can't always assume that `apt-get update` is run from GUI applications...

Comment: Interesting... Might there be some unusual networking situation between you and the server that is better handled when you run `apt-get` than by the automatic check performed by running the Software Updater / Update Manager? Do you use an HTTP proxy? And are you able to you make it happen again, or has it happened just the one time? If it's an isolated anomaly, I wonder if maybe the problem is due to a temporary server misconfiguration. What mirror do you use? With more info, maybe I could improve my answer. (Btw, is this intended as a separate answer, or should it be converted to a comment?)

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider the example of installing [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It will check the repositories for available updates.

Whereas

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

will install VLC media player from the repositories which we searched for.

If you had logged in as a root user (administrator), you don't have to use `sudo`, because you already have the super user privileges.