# How to reinstall Terminal?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, gnome-terminal, dependencies

While fixing package dependencies, the terminal application went missing, and now I cannot locate the application. Is there a way to reinstall the terminal application?

Answer (score 40):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (to enter a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)), log in with with your account and install the package `gnome-terminal` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

When you type passwords into a text-only virtual console, you don't see anything on the screen. That's normal.

Return to Unity (or whatever other desktop environment you're currently running) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: +1 for using cli and not Ubuntu Software Center. By the way, you only need to press alt+F7 or powerkey+F7. There's no need for the ctrl if you're not in X.

Comment: If you are in TTY1 and want to get back to TTY7 pretty sure you need to press Ctrl+Alt+F7 for that... Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Try it. For me, I certainly don't need the ctrl.

Comment: As someone who has never used cli environment (TTY) to operate an OS; I was stumped as to where would I enter that command. Things got clear after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: @Vreality you were right! ;) lol, leaning something new everyday. Cheers

Comment: @Aditya Being able to use CLI is great skill; I'm glad you learned a little about it today.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, but a non graphical interface is true cli while a terminal program is just an emulator.

Comment: @Vreality What Ctrl+Alt+F1 gives you *is not what a "terminal emulator" emulates*. Both graphical console apps and a *virtual consoles* are *virtual* in the same sense. There is no way in which a graphically presented shell is not truly a *command-line interface* (CLI). **However, it's true** that when one uses GNOME Terminal, one is using a graphical interface *as well*, and while techniques for using a virtual console apply to a graphical terminal, many graphical terminal users are unfamiliar with techniques particularly useful when there are no GUI niceties for scrolling back and the like.

Comment: @EliahKagan Very true. But scrolling is still possible (shift+pgUp/pgDown).

Comment: When I did that Ctrl+Alt+F1 on my Ubuntu 15.10 system, I got a black screen with no functionality and had to reboot.  Whatever that did surely did NOT work.   :-(

Answer (score 22):

#### The Middle Way

[This totally non-graphical way](https://askubuntu.com/a/243128/22949), and [this totally graphical way](https://askubuntu.com/a/243141/22949), are both excellent. But there is a third way, too.

**Ubuntu comes with another (simpler) graphical terminal program that you can fall back on!**

If you cannot use [the Terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) (for users of other Ubuntu flavors, this applies to the [Konsole](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/konsole.1.html), [Xfce4 Terminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xfce4-terminal.1.html), and [LXTerminal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html), too), **you can still use [`xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xterm.1.html)**.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `xterm`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Typing xterm into Unity. (This is the Alt+F2 menu, but typing into the normal dash is usually as effective.)]

Here you can install `gnome-terminal` with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

<sup>You'll notice my command is a little different from [Bruno Pereira's](https://askubuntu.com/a/243128/22949). Having recently performed lots of package management, you may not need to run `sudo apt-get update`. (Unless your dependency problem was from `apt-get` and you didn't run it with `update` before, then you definitely need to.) [You can decide.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)</sup>

[image: xterm (running on Unity 2D in Ubuntu 12.10 Precise Pangolin, but regardless of version and UI, it will look similar).]

Ubuntu's `xterm` is very basic in style. As far as I know, there's no *GUI* way for `xterm` to scroll back, save history, change font and font size, or anything like that. The actual shell's capabilities will of course be the same as in any Terminal, since it's still [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html). (Or [whatever you set it to be](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chsh.1.html).)

#### Alternatives

If you have a longer-term problem of any kind with the GNOME Terminal, you can use `xterm`, but it is not as friendly and (in some ways) not as sophisticated as GNOME Terminal.

If you continue to have trouble getting GNOME Terminal working but you're able to install software in general, you can install:

- [Xfce's terminal](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/start) – [xfce4-terminal [image: Install xfce4-terminal]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xfce4-terminal)
- [LXDE's terminal](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal) – [lxterminal [image: Install lxterminal]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lxterminal)

*You should not use [Konsole](http://kde.org/applications/system/konsole/) for this, however, unless you already have KDE installed. Installing it usually pulls in lots of KDE-related packages as dependencies.*

Comment: I just get a spinning icon before the word `xterm` after this step: `Press Alt+F2, type xterm, and press Enter.`

Answer (score 8):

Well you can do with Ubuntu Software Center or (if you have it) the Synaptic Package Manager.

Just type *terminal* in the search box of either application, and you'll get what ever you want.

Another way to install it in the Software Center is to click:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using a single command,
it actually works for me..
You can also try using software center by searching the item in your peppermint device.

```sh
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```