# How to reinstall gnome-terminal?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I dont know exactly what happened. When I open my terminal window, it completely cracked. I dont anything editing this window. How to i reinstall gnome-terminal ?

I have tried the below post's solutions,
[How to reinstall Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243124/how-to-reinstall-terminal)

But, it didn't solve my problem.

[image]

It would be great, if give any solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: The question you linked to seems to be about reinstalling gnome-terminal *when it's been removed*: to reinstall it when it's currently installed but screwed up, you probably need to add the flag `--reinstall` to the command i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal`

Comment: I have tried with your command. But, that problem has not solved.

Comment: In that case, the problem is likely not with any of the files in the `gnome-terminal` package - perhaps it is something in your local (user) configuration? Do you see the same behaviour if logged in to a different account / guest account?

Comment: @steeldriver I have tried different users too .... Still, blank window only opened. I have tried to execute exit command in this window. It works. But, content has not displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the next paragraph to its end before doing anything!

Switch to a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. It also works for <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>. If something is running on TTY1 (used <kbd>F1</kbd>), use the next one. Log in and enter `sudo apt-get purge gnome-terminal`. To get back to the graphical session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

You might want to remove the profile files before reinstalling `gnome-terminal` (by typing in `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`). To do so, delete `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`, if it exist on your system. I have no idea where it is on Ubuntu 15.04, so maybe google this one.

Edit: I figured out the path on Ubuntu 15.04: `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have execute above solutions. Problem has not solved :-( . My OS- ubuntu14.04

Comment: I've never had something like this and have no idea how to solve it. However, you can try to install a new terminal. Mate Terminal is pretty much the same thing. `sudo apt-get install mate-terminal`

Comment: Did you delete the files mentioned in my answer?

Comment: sorry.... small mistake.. It works well... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you ran into this problem after upgrading python2.7 to python3.5, anyway the solution is rather easy:
Just open xterm and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install gnome-terminal
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

if it didn't work either ways though, run `sudo apt-get remove python3` first and repeat the steps.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

open xterm or a tty terminal, and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the application (terminal or xterm) doesn't work because it doesn't create the ~/.bashrc file. The solution is to create/edit this file with appropriate logic. :-) You can find some modified version of these files in extenstion.gnome.org