# Terminal has lost its colours

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash

In terminal, the usual prompt text `user@machine` isn't green/blue as usual. Instead is is just white like the rest of the text. If I ssh into my server however, the colours are the same. Perhaps I've accidentally hit a button?

The settings in Edit → Profile Preferences → Colors look fine. The selected palette shown there is *Linux Console*.

I've tried using `apt remove gnome-terminal && apt install gnome-terminal` but that still hasn't worked. I've also tried using the MATE Terminal method and using UXTerm but both of which are doing the same issue.

Comment: "Edit > Profile Preferences > Colors" and look at the selected "Palette".

Comment: It seems fine. The palette is Linux Console

Comment: what about XTerm ? if the problem only on terminal try to reinstall http://askubuntu.com/questions/684180/how-to-reinstall-gnome-terminal

Comment: I've tried using `apt remove gnome-terminal && apt install gnome-terminal` but that still hasn't worked. I've also tried using the mate terminal method and using UXTerm but both of which are doing the same issue.

Comment: may you reinstall but preferences still saved try to reset preferences third and fourth answers  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14487/how-to-reset-the-terminal-properties-and-preferences
and please make a mention when you replay

Comment: if reset not working install new terminal instead of gnome like this 
http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-guake-terminal-and-guake-indicator-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-and-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander/

Comment: @MohamedSlama as I said, the colours are fine if I ssh into my file server but if I ssh into the laptop the colours go

Comment: @MohamedSlama this is it http://imgur.com/ptyShAm

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this issue when I accidentally deleted my `~/.bashrc` file. Changing the Profile Preferences as stated in a comment above did not work. Since I completely lost my `~/.bashrc` file, I simply copied `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc` like this:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

After a logout and login, my terminal colors were back to normal.

One could also look at `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to see if anything related to color is missing from their `~/.bashrc` file.

This may not be the solution to OP's exact problem but I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I my case I also had the `.profile` missing, which could be recovered from the same location.

Answer (score 13):

I think you delete your .bashrc file, so you can use this command:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Answer (score 8):

I copied `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to   `~/.bashrc`

then `source .bashrc`

and  terminal Color restored!

Comment: for more clarification about this issue ( in my experience) 
the issue is back after restart ,So I have fixed this by deleting ``.bash_profile`` and using ``.profile``  instead  basedإ on this response : https://askubuntu.com/questions/517677/how-do-i-get-a-colored-bash

Answer (score 3):

For me i was using lxterminal in lubuntu and the color for the user@machine not working. I had to uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` in ~/.bashrc to make the geen colour appear

Answer (score 1):

It might also have to do with `color_prompt` variable which is defined in the `~/.bashrc` file. The block responsible for defining the color scheme is :

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Just try peeking at its value by adding `echo $color_prompt` before the above block. If it is not "yes", then now you can overwrite the value as @plettech has suggested.
Also, just running `source ~/.bashrc` can sometimes help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Open up ~/.bashrc

And enter on a line by itself:

```
color_prompt=yes
```

worked for me