# Not able to update or upgrade after upgrading from Python 3.10.12 to Python 3.11

Tags: command-line, gnome, upgrade, python

I have a complete backup for starters. Second, I was testing an application that required me to upgrade from Python 3.10.12 to Python 3.11, and now Gnome Terminal is not working, and I am unable to update or upgrade Ubuntu Pro 22.04.X. Please advise.

Myles.

Comment: Search this site for python update broke  No application should need to change system default python (or compiler).  There are other ways to install new versions of anything you want without breaking the system.

Comment: Congratulations: You have made the second most-common mistake that leads people to AskUbuntu. You have changed the version of a critical system component (Python3), and thereby destroyed your system. Sorry. If you know how to change it back, do so. If you don't know how to change it back, then reinstall Ubuntu and restore from your backup. `sudo` removes the guardrails and permits you to poke at the spinning gears inside...but spinning gears don't like to be poked.

Comment: You should never upgrade system-installed version of Python in Ubuntu. You can't do it in normal way; no package installed from system repositories will require you to do that,also there isn't a replacement package in system repositories you can upgrade to. Once an Ubuntu release is released, system-default Python version for that release is fixed and should never be changed. If your application requires a specific version of Python, you should install a separate version for that application only and don't touch the default one. You have broken your system and the best you can do is reinstall.

Comment: After fixing this problem, if you want to install a specific version of Python without breaking Ubuntu, then use Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/download/. It will install a specific version of python in a container, without disrupting the system python.

Comment: Don't change the defaults of system critical tools; eg. if you change the default of python3; all Ubuntu tools that rely on it will either fail to function, or WORSE appear to work & just corrupt things. As already stated you should restore backups, reverse what you did, or if using a Desktop system (*you weren't specific with details*) you can non-destructively re-install your system too (less ideal for servers, but servers are easier to fix usually).

Comment: Terminal does not open at all.

Comment: How am I to run line commands in terminal when it does not open please advis?

Comment: Try running commands in a virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+F4).

Comment: the key combinations of (ctrl+alt+F4) is not working. I am going to try one more option and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using re-installing the gnome-terminal.

First, you'd like to take a back of the gnome setting if you configured it well. Here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1056392/1774643

Second, re-install gnome-terminal Here - https://askubuntu.com/a/684186/1774643

Or you can try using the Python virtual environment - `python3 -m venv myvenv`

Comment: First I reinstalled ubuntu-gnome-desktop sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop; The desktop was still not quite right and gnome terminal still would not work. I researched some more and find this command sudo update-alternatives --config python3. A screen popped up asking me to select between 3 alternatives and I selected 0 ust/bin/python3.10 110 automode and terminal, plus update notifier, updated as well and now everything is working properly.