# Cannot start terminal on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: command-line, 15.10

I have a problem with terminal. When I click on the "terminal" icon on the left side, nothing happens - cursor just stays in wait mode for a few seconds. I tried to reinstall gnome-terminal from tty, but it didn't help. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you changed the default profile settings in your terminal in an earlier session?

Comment: Can you run it from the alt-F2 box?

Comment: Install some other Terminal (Guake, Tilda, `xfce4-terminal` or whatever) and run `gnome-terminal` *from* the new Terminal. It should spit out some error message.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+T work? (It should open a terminal.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, use these:

#### 1. Ctrl + Alt + F2

#### 2. UXTerm

Go to Unity Dash Search and type in 'UXTerm'

#### 3. XTerm

Go to Unity Dash Search and type in 'XTerm'

#### 4. Look for terminal alternatives in Software Center

Answer (score -1):

Terminal in itself is just another software to access a shell(Bash) there are many of these around gnome-terminal, konsole, xterm, rxvt, kvt, nxterm, and eterm.

try installing an alternative!

this is an alternative however it won't fix the issue!

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243124/how-to-reinstall-terminal) which provides details on how to install gnome-terminal maybe you can try removing it and installing it again!

you can try [this](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/482) to fix a package, however you need to execute these commands from a terminal alternative!