# Ubuntu 23.10 Terminal turned into a text editor

Tags: gnome-terminal, 23.10

The **Terminal** suddenly does not accept commands anymore and basically behaves like a text editor.

[image]

The last commands that I put in before this happened was just some `nvm` commands, i.e. `nvm alias default 20.11.0`, `nvm ls`, etc.

Restart did not fix it.

I haven't seen this behaviour before, did I perhaps accidentally hit a shortcut that switched it into a different mode? If so, how do I reset it?

I have Ubuntu 23.10 with all the latest updates, GNOME Terminal Version 3.49.92 for GNOME 45.

Comment: May need re-installing - Does this answer your question? [How to reinstall Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243124/how-to-reinstall-terminal)

Comment: Rename `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc_disabled` and relaunch your terminal to see if it becomes normal again.

Comment: This is likely due to some non-terminating (or at least, long running) command in one of the shell startup files (typically `~/.bashrc`, assuming you are using the default terminal profile)

Comment: press ctrl+c keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As steeldriver said, this is the symptom of a long-running process. Since it is nvm, this is completely reasonable. nvm caused my shell to take significantly longer to start as it tries to load a bunch of files from disk.

Try pressing CTRL+C (multiple times if it doesn't work, then CTRL+\) at that prompt to cancel the long-running command (usually nvm). You should end up at your normal prompt, possibly without color. When Linux runs a terminal command, the terminal subsystem buffers the input and echoes it *before* sending it to any application, unless the specific command bothered to disable echo.

As Raffa said, the problem is inside `~/.bashrc`. See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/782 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556330/run-nvm-use-automatically-every-time-theres-a-nvmrc-file-on-the-directory , and https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1261 . I personally use something like the following edit to my `.bashrc`:

```bash
# Comment out the lines the nvm installer added by default
#[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
#[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
#. <(npm completion)

# Only load nvm when necessary
alias nvm='unalias nvm && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm'
alias node='unalias node && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && node'
```

This may cause some subtle bugs, but it greatly reduces the impact of nvm on my terminal startup time. This is especially useful for working with non-Node commands.

Answer (score -1):

Try booting in single user mode using shortcut ( for me it is ctrl+alt+F4).

Then see if you are able to run commands. If yes, then go to
/usr/bin/ and check if gnome-terminal is present. Also check modified date.

First check if internet is reachable and then Try running

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
```

`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

to see if it fixes the issue.

If this doesn't work, you can go to ubuntu software and install any other terminal like terminator, guake etc.