# Fresh installation running rather sluggish

Tags: performance

Good day! Today I installed ubuntu on my home desktop (win 7 is the main OS). To this day I was running it in a virtual machine, but since I will do some of my work from home I decided to install it as a second OS.

The problem is that the installation runs rather slow. Nothing huge, however, on my work PC which is weaker some simple commands like `apt-cache search` or the creation of a database are made instantly. Same goes for the virtual machine. On this installation though, it takes a second or so for the basic command (like the apt-cache) and a couple of seconds for the creation of a database.

It is nothing fatal, however it is annoying to some extent and I am wondering what can be causing this. I do not recall seeing any option for limiting the processing power which the PC should be able to use(in the installation).

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

EDIT: Earlier today I updated everything via the package manager (`sudo apt-get update` ) I am not sure if this covers the drivers or not.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get update` doesn't actually install any updates. Although I do understand the confusion. What `sudo apt-get update` actually does is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do), in a question also asked on AskUbuntu. After apt-get update you will probably want to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Even **easier** would be using the software & updates tool available in recent Ubuntu versions.

Try installing the latest updates and see if it really makes a difference. Since I don't really know about any of the hardware you are using I can't really help you with driver issues. From the software & updates application you can find proprietary drivers, which might boost your performance. **Be cautious** though, try using tested versions. Considering your experience with Ubuntu you might be in for even more issues if you use untested versions that *might* be unstable.