# sudo apt-get update gives me the same list everytime

Tags: updates

I upgraded by the command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the update finished, the result is the same; the next time I run the command, the same result appears, something like:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
.
.
.
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en_IN
Fetched 217 kB in 1min 21s (2,648 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

I searched for a solution, but it seems I am the only one with this problem. If this question is a duplicate, could someone give me a link to the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get update downloads the package lists from the repositories and ***updates*** them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories and PPAs.

From `man apt-get`

```
Used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. The indexes of
available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified in /etc/apt
/sources.list(5). An update should always be performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade.
```

So basically it shows only the repositories that has been updated

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Comment: Thanks for your response.But my question is why is it downloading/updating same packages every time I run update command.

Comment: @rvr93 downloading _what_ packages? The output you show is just the list of packages, no packages are downloaded when you run `apt-get update` and the output will always be the same since, as Stormivux explained, that command simply re-downloads the list of available packages.

Comment: OK my bad.So if I am not wrong by update command it shows all the packages on system and updates wherever possible right?

Comment: @rvr93 It doesnt show the packages but checks whether there is an update at the main repository for the ackages installed in your system. So the lines you see are the repository addresses that it checks for update.But to see if any changes are there or to upgrade then you need to run apt-get upgrade. So first apt-get update then apt-get upgrade.