# Upgrade always recommend the same list of upgrades

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management

Before write this question I saw these two similar questions ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190828/apt-get-upgrade-stuck-at-the-same-package), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451179/sudo-apt-get-update-gives-me-the-same-list-everytime)), but none of them are exactly my problem.
Once per day, when I run the `sudo apt-get upgrade` it returns the same list of upgrades as follows:

```
$sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libegl1-mesa
  libegl1-mesa-drivers libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa
  libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2
  mesa-common-dev mesa-opencl-icd mesa-vdpau-drivers
22 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

In the same day, if I run the command again it doesn't show the list. However, if I run the command the next day, the same list is returned.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (XENIAL) MATE 1.12.2, kernel 4.9.0-040900-generic

Assistance most appreciated.

Comment: If you reboot, does the same list return on the same day? Is it *exactly* the same list each time?

Comment: Yes, even when I reboot the system, in the same day, the list doesn't appear. And yes, it's the exactly same list, plus some new upgrades of that day.

Comment: Your terminal-output looks like you just have to press enter. `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: Yes, the problem is not upgrade this list, I can upgrade it without error when I type 'y' and press enter. The problem is the constant suggestion of upgrade this list over and over again