# How to install ImageMagick on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, imagemagick

I need to install ImageMagick for giving support to a Ruby application I currently am working on. This runs into a VM on which Ubuntu 12.04 is installed (particularly, hashicorp/precise32 release in Vagrant).

I run:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing
```

And after accepting the changes, I'm met with the following errors:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libjasper1 i386 1.900.1-13ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libjasper1 i386 1.900.1-13ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper1_1.900.1-13ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.
```

At this point, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. I've checked the repositories and the files are there, except that they are labeled `ubuntu0.2_i386.deb` instead of `ubuntu0.1_i386.deb`. Would it be safe for me to overwrite 0.1 by 0.2? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be that your sources are out of date - try running `sudo apt-get update` beforehand.

Comment: @Wilf That did the trick indeed -- if you want to post it as an answer with some background on sources + updates, I'll be more than happy to accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that your sources are out of date, so are asking for old URLs instead of the current ones - try running `sudo apt-get update` before installing stuff.

If you want to see what it does, read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do).