# How can I update a particular software through Terminal without sudo apt-get update?

Tags: apt, package-management

For general updates I use:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I want to update my Ovito software from 2.3.2 to 2.6.2, which is not achieved by the above command.

How can I update a particular software through Terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just upgrading a single package, do:

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

One caveat is that this will of course install the package if not installed already, to only upgrade a package (and not install the package if not installed):

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <package_name>
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade dos2unix
```

---

Also note that, `sudo apt-get update` does not upgrade a package to the latest version, it just synchronizes the package lists (and metadata) between the repositories and local files.

Perhaps you meant:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which will upgrade all packages to their latest versions.

Comment: please elaborate role of package lists, metadata,local files and repositories

Comment: @sumitsharma ummm, that would be out of scope of your question..check http://askubuntu.com/q/222348/216503