# apt-get full-upgrade includes updating (or only both types of upgrading)?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I understand that `apt-get full-upgrade` "includes" or "encapsulates" `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`, but does it also include `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

`apt full-upgrade` works the same as `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

You still need to update your package database with `apt update` first.

Note: there is officially no such thing as `apt-get full-upgrade`.  The `full-upgrade` verb can only be used with `aptitude` or `apt`.  On `apt-get` you need to use `dist-upgrade` for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, here is a little explanation:

- `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories and PPAs.
- `apt-get upgrade` will fetch new versions of packages existing on the machine if APT knows about these new versions by way of apt-get update.
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` will do the same job which is done by apt-get upgrade, plus it will also intelligently handle the dependencies, so it might remove obsolete packages or add new ones.

For further explanation follow this link: [What does “sudo apt-get update” do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Comment: Thumb up for the didactic explanation. So you say that update only updates versions list and not the software itself? If so, I assume that update must always precede an upgrade, in Linux.

Comment: Yes, `apt-get update` just verifies if there is a new update and modifies the "index", the packages are downloaded when you execute `apt-get upgrade`, you can try the following: 1) Execute first `apt-get upgrade` at anytime, maybe some packages will be updated. 2) Then execute `apt-get update`, and again `apt-get upgrade`, you will see that after doing this `apt-get upgrade` will download more packages, because the list of updates was refreshed by `apt-get update`.