# Ubuntu 18.04. Can't install python3-pip package. Synaptic can't find a file

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, python3, pip

I tried to install python3-pip using Synaptic. Before beginning installation, it gave the following message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-42.45_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

I instructed Synaptic to proceed with the installation. Afterwards, I found the missing file on a Ubuntu mirror site after finding only broken links to it on the Ubuntu site.

After installing the missing file, a `pip3 --version` query states that it is not installed and Synaptic shows that python3-pip is not installed.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package database is out of date - that old package was withdrawn and superseded by a newer version.

Run `apt update` to update your package database.

Then apt will try to download the correct package version and the install will work.

Comment: I ran the following sequence, which was successful: (1)sudo apt update (2)sudo apt upgrade (3)sudo apt install python3-pip

Comment: Had same issue in dockerfile, thanks to answer above, changed apt-get to apt and it helped:

```
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
```