# I get a trust list error at the end of sudo apt update

Tags: package-management

Shows after `sudo apt get update` - not sure what needs fixing:

```
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
Updating Mono key store
Mono Certificate Store Sync - version 6.12.0.139
Populate Mono certificate store from a concatenated list of certificates.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

Importing into legacy system store:
I already trust 131, your new list has 129
Import process completed.

Importing into BTLS system store:
I already trust 131, your new list has 129
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Setting up mono-devel (6.12.0.139-0xamarin3+ubuntu2004b1) ...
```

Log in and always get a large list of updates needed - run apt update and its fine for "a while". Log in and the updates are still showing an issue

```
161 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Comment: nothing to do with sudo apt update - this runs correctly - just at the end I get the legacy system store and BTLS system store complaints - the update run then 2 or 3 days later it says update needed.  The trust list needs to match and it doesn't match.  Several days and I am up to date - I will reboot and see if the error returns (I would like to re-word the question but I don't know how to do that)

Comment: I mean that you need full cycle - `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` or  `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (to get upgrades with new dependencies).

Comment: yes I thought I said that - full cycle - I know what that is - I have been running since 14.xx   But to say again - sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade shows all updates but then after all it complains about not matching.  I showed then beginning and end but I guess you need to see all the nonsense in between that has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Drive full error caused the issue - fixed drive - problem is fixed