# installing nginx: E: Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found

Tags: 20.04, lts, nginx, webserver

Whenever I try to install NGINX on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common libappindicator1 libc++1
  libc++1-10 libc++abi1-10 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libgconf-2-4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter
  libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream nginx-common nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter
  libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream nginx nginx-common nginx-core
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 602 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,134 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 nginx-common all 1.18.0-0ubuntu1
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter amd64 1.18.0-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter amd64 1.18.0-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-mail
```

and so on...
and then:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried doing that, but it doesn't work at all.
I also tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Any help?

Comment: When did you last update your software lists?  (ie. `sudo apt update`) as the package in your messages is outdated & not the latest; ie. ` libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter | 1.18.0-0ubuntu1.2 | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` is what you'd be downloading if your software lists were up-to-date.  (the package you're after was included on initial install media and is now outdated; did you get any messages for your `apt-get update` as that will provided your issues; ie. *errors, warnings or missing lines*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)