# Permissions Denied error using linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, lubuntu, sudo

I am editing the question with my attempt on running `sudo apt-get upgrade`

I can not upgrade the files after running that command. It tells me that it found files to upgrade but says 'failed to fetch' every file to found. Does that clarify my post? Still new to this sorry and my college professor is the issue of not explaining clearly and lack of knowledge.

Comment: Most folks use `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Is there a particular reason you are skipping the `sudo` part? It's an important part.

Comment: Advice: DON'T blindly copy shell commands from some random online instructions. Understand what they do first. Taking the time to understand will make whatever you are trying to accomplish both maintainable and much more satisfying.

Comment: The `sudo` elevates your privileges (*super user do*) which is necessary to make changes to your box (upgrading packages can make lots of changes; those maybe official changes or someone using `sudo` may have added 3rd party & potential harmful sources to be changed as well - the need of `sudo` should make you stop & think about the action before you do it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

Comment: It helps us if you post the exact error. Copy and paste the output into your question and please format it as code. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to but it continues to tell me the file is to big, it is just a screenshot from my laptop too.

Comment: sounds like you may be offline ... launch your browser and confirm you can connect to the net ... if offline then setup your wifi or ...

Comment: "Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xwayland_1.20,11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2_arm64.deb Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' "

Comment: okay you're correct its that im not connected to wifi im going to try and fix it right now

Comment: Please add additional details to your question, and make your question complete with facts. You've tagged Lubuntu, but your last comment refers to http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xorg-server/ and mentions a different architecture to Lubuntu (where *amd64* only is downloadable) for *arm64* so these missing details should be provided in your question. If you're using *amd64* then why have you ports in your sources?  If you're using *arm64* you haven't mentioned it & are your sources correct for that architecture (no *amd64* sources wrongly added?)

Answer (score 0):

Some commands (such as `apt`/`apt-get` (by default on Ubuntu) require you to prefix them with `sudo`, so that they run as the superuser (Ubuntu equivalent of a Windows administrator, ish). There are a few exceptions, such as if you are running as a root shell (indicated usually by your prompt ending with a `#` instead of a `$`, but running `sudo apt-get upgrade` should resolve the issue.