# Errors when running "sudo apt update" Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic with Hetzner

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, sudo, mirrors

When I run

```
sudo apt -y update
```

I get

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                   
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                               
Hit:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-backports InRelease                             
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-security InRelease            
Hit:7 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                     
Fetched 88.7 kB in 1s (144 kB/s)                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure what to do to fix that, I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an error.

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: Please don't close this question or I will reopen it. The canonical duplicate question for this is so difficult to understand that it's completely unusable in my opinion.

Comment: @Karel then shouldn't we fix the canonical question and answers?

Comment: Usually I would say yes,  we should fix the canonical question and answers, but this time the accepted answer to this question is good enough that this question deserves to be left open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, just an information after you update your package list.

Check the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do) about what do `sudo apt update` do.

You can try with the hint `apt list --upgradable` to see the upgradable list

or

`sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade the upgradable package.